# Matrix Analysis (Select the minimum elements of the rows to create a vector)

Tags: real-analysis, matrices, algebraic-geometry, optimization

I have a practical study and need this process "Select the minimum elements of the rows of a matrix to create a vector". Theoretically, the process is possible, but I need a purely mathematical basis as definitions or theories that support this process, which I will explain in the following example.

Illustrative example, consider the matrix $A$

> $A=\left( \begin{array}{ccccc}  1 & 0 & 0  \\  0 & 1 & 0 \\  1 & 1 & 1 
>  \\ \end{array} \right)$

I need to select the minimal element in each row of matrix $A$. Then arrange the items as a set or vector

> (0,0,1)

What is the mathematical process that was based on them. My attempts to explain this process mathematically

Assume matrix

> $A=\left( \begin{array}{ccccc}  V_1   \\  V_2  \\  V_3 
>  \\ \end{array} \right)$

Where $V_1=\{1,0,0\},V_2=\{0,1,0\}$ and $V_3=\{1,1,1\}$

> $min(A)=\left( \begin{array}{ccccc}  min(V_1)   \\  min(V_2)  \\  min(V_3) 
>  \\ \end{array} \right)=\left( \begin{array}{ccccc}  0   \\  0  \\ 1 
>  \\ \end{array} \right)$

therefore we get $min(A)$ as state vector  :

> $$V=min(A)=(0,0,1)$$
>
> Some suggestions:Assuming you have a classical computer and given a
>   vector $v$, find its smallest element. To do so just do a linear scan.
>   Now, repeat this process for each row. Complexity of the approach:
>   $O(mn)$.
>
> How to write down the process of "using the min elts of the rows of a
>   matrix to create a vector" using mathematical notation?
>
> If the process naturally arises in applied mathematics (say perhaps in
>   game theory)?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: A crystal clear problem with a crystal clear solution by yourself, namely an algorithm. I'm completely at lost what else sort of "deep mathematics" would be desirable here.

Comment: @HandeBruijn I know how to solve it, but I would like to know some aspect of this subject with thanks and appreciation

Comment: I don't understand your question. Are you asking how to write down the process of "using the min elts of the rows of a matrix to create a vector" using mathematical notation? Or are you asking if the process naturally arises in applied mathematics (say perhaps in game theory)?

Comment: @AlexVong Can you answer two questions ... Thanks for your comment.

Comment: We can try and guess what you actually mean, but frankly you are much more likely to get a useful reply if you eliminate the doubt. Do you need a formula for the minimum of $n$ numbers? Do you need to references to the axiomatic characterization of the real numbers which allow us to compare numbers and find a minimum? Do you need proof of your complexity analysis? Do you need $f=(f_1,f_2, \dotsc f_m)^T$, where $f_i = \min \{a_{ij} \: | \:j \in \{1,2,\dots,n\}$ which is the shortest possible notation for what you are doing? These are all valid interpretations of you text!!!

Comment: @CarlChristian Thanks for this logical explanation ... I am trying hard to put  mathematical notation to a clear process in the example given in the question ... I searched a lot of references but I can not find the use of this  mathematical notation .... Note that this  mathematical notation solves a practical problem.(can you given a proof of complexity analysis?)

Comment: Yes, finding the smallest value among $n$ numbers requires $n-1$ comparisons and a proof by mathematical induction can be written if that is indeed what you need. However, the notation $\min$ and $\max$ is universally understood. There are even MathJaX commands with those names which allow you to typeset them.